# Arithmetic Overflow error converting to data type int while reorganizing index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, database-administration

We have a table of 3+ billion rows and one of the non clustered indexes that we are trying to reorganize contains only one `numeric(18,0)` column. It is a foreign key column and recently went past the threshold for reorganization. I was wondering if anybody could shed some light on the cause of this issue.

Following is the statement (names modified) that runs as a part of index maintenance.

```
ALTER INDEX [IX_IndexName] ON  [DB].[dbo].[TableName] REORGANIZE
```

CREATE TABLE STATEMENT

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl](
[ProBillEditLogTbl_Key] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION 
  NOT NULL,
[ProBill_Key] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[EditUserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EditDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EditDescription] [varchar](2000) NOT NULL,
[EditApplication] [varchar](25) NULL,
[msrepl_tran_version] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ProBillEditLogType_key] [int] NULL,
[OldProbillNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OldPbStatusCode_Key] [int] NULL,
[OldStatusReason] [int] NULL,
[EditedFrom] [varchar](100) NULL,
[ArchiveKeepIND] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ProBillEditLogTbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [ProBillEditLogTbl_Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
 [DF_ProBillEditLogTbl_EditDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [EditDate]
 GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR 
[msrepl_tran_version]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl] ADD  DEFAULT (1) FOR 
[ProBillEditLogType_key]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_ProBillEditLogTbl_ProbillEditLogTypeTbl] FOREIGN 
KEY([ProBillEditLogType_key])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ProbillEditLogTypeTbl] ([ProBillEditLogType_key])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_ProBillEditLogTbl_ProbillEditLogTypeTbl]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_ProBillEditLogTBL_ProBillTBL] FOREIGN KEY([ProBill_Key])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ProBillTBL] ([ProBill_Key])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

CREATE INDEX Statement

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProBillEditLogTbl_Probill_key_only] ON [dbo]. 
[ProBillEditLogTbl]
(
    [ProBill_Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = 
ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [Indexes01]
GO
```

ERROR SHOW  :

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. [SQLSTATE 22003] (Error 8115). The step failed.
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. [SQLSTATE 22003] (Error 8115).  The step failed.

Comment: Can you post the Index Creation SQL and the Table Creation SQL?  It seems strange it would reference an INT data type if the index only contains a numeric column.

Comment: Any untrusted constraints in this table?

Comment: can you use: DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.TableName',reseed,0)

Comment: @Dave.Gugg ...added the create scripts.

Comment: @JacobH  no untrusted constraints found

Comment: @CR241 dangerous operation

Comment: I agree, i wouldn't just reseed your table. What does `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[ProBillEditLogTbl]', NORESEED);` return, out of interest? Is it a value higher than 2,147,483,647? I assume so, considering you have over 3B rows.

Comment: The identity column is also numeric(18,0) and it's current value is 4,718,801,684.

Comment: You say REORGANIZE runs as a part of index maintenance. Are you sure this is what cause problem?

Comment: Not saying Reorganize is causing the problem but something else is for Reorganize to fail. The index maintenance job identifies the indexes that are over certain threshold and that day ONLY ONE Index was identified and was tried to reorganize. I even tried to run it manually on  management studio and same issue.

Comment: Is this table being replicated?  If so, can you check that the replicated table has the same definition?

Comment: It's in AlwaysOn Availability Group. Yes, the definition is same. The secondary is the read only and can't be in a different state than than of primary.